# How do I get a counter variable to be unique for each line of a file

Tags: bash

So what I have is 2 directories that have the same files, except that directory a is today's data and directory b is yesterday's data. What I want to do is compare the files and output the results into 3 columns, which will be the file name, whether or not the files are identical, and how many days the files have been the same.

What I have so far is:

```
ls ./dropzone_current > files.txt

is_identical=false


filename="files.txt"
while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    declare -i counter 
    diff -qs ./dropzone_current/$name ./dropzone_backup/$name
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
    is_identical=false
    counter=0
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$is_identical" "$counter" >> test.txt

    else
    counter=$((counter + 1))
    is_identical=true
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$is_identical" "$counter" >> test.txt
    fi


done < "$filename"
```

Essentially, everything works except the counter. I need the counter to be unique to each file name that's being compared, and then update every time the script is run (once a day) but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: If you want it to keep state across several runs of the script, you will need to drop a file onto disk or other some nonvolatile medium which your script will read upon startup for initialization, and write upon exit for future reference.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.

Comment: @drewbenn that actually would be perfect. Do you have an example of how I could do that, or a link to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments to my other answer and to your question, it sounds like what you're really looking for is a way to track changes to a set of files.  This is commonly known as version (or revision) control.  One common engine for this that is generally installed on a system is `git`.

To implement this, pick a location to store what we'll call the 'repository', which will store a copy of the files and track all of the changes thereto.  We'll call this location `/path/to/repository`.  Create that directory, and run the command `git init`.  This will set up the repository.  Copy the files into the directory, and we will now 'commit' the current state to the repository:

```
git add *
git commit -m "Initial commit of files"
```

Then, you can simply watch the delivery location and update the repository as needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
repo='/path/to/repository'
dropbox='/path/to/delivery/'

cd $repo
for file in *; do
    if ! diff "${repo}/$file" "${dropbox}/$file"; then
        cp -p "${dropbox}/$file" ${repo}/
        git add "$file"
    fi
done
git commit -m "Update for $(date)"
```

This is a quick-and-dirty script that doesn't handle files with spaces in their names, or files being added or removed from the feed particularly well, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Fortunately none of the files have spaces, they all use underscores. This will definitely help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to keep state across several runs of the script, you will need to drop a file onto disk or other some nonvolatile medium which your script will read upon startup for initialization, and write upon exit for future reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
dropfile='/path/to/your/counterfile'
if [[ -r "$dropfile" ]]; then
    counter=$(cat "$dropfile" )
else
    counter=0
fi
trap 'echo $counter > "$dropfile"' EXIT

echo "This script has run $counter times."
counter=$((counter+1))
```

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to have the counter variable represent a (possibly) different number for each file? So, if today's version of file1 and yesterday's version have been the same for 2 days, then counter=2, but if today's version of file 2 and yesterday's version of file2 have been the same for 5 days, then counter=5

Comment: As @drewbenn mentions in a comment on your question, it sounds like you're trying to reinvent version control.  I would look into setting up a git repository (`git init`), and you can use `diff` to test your delivery location for new files.  If one is found, copy it into your repository and commit the change.  You can then have a log `git log` of each time a file is changed, and can easily review exactly what the changes were.

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into that. There's no sense in trying to reinvent things that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a revision control system. For example, using mercurial, `hg init` in the directory where files are stored. Then once a day (probably as a `cron` job right after the new files are placed there), `hg addremove` and `hg commit`.

Then to run your report, you can loop over each file (`for filename in dropzone/*; do`) and get the timestamp it was last committed with e.g. `hg log -l 1 --template "{date(date, '%s')}\n" "$filename"`. The `%s` will give you the UNIX seconds timestamp; you can get the current value with `$(date +%s)`, subtract, and convert that, roughly, into days.

Any VCS (`svn`, `git`, etc.) will work just as well for you, so just use what you're comfortable with.